# Sugarcrm / Suitecrm smarty preg_replace

Tags: smarty, sugarcrm

Ive got the error below

```
Deprecated: preg_replace(): The /e modifier is deprecated, use preg_replace_callback instead in C:\xampp\htdocs\suitecrm\include\Smarty\Smarty_Compiler.class.php on line 268
```

I have changed the PHP.ini file to stop showing deprecated errors, but it still shows up

```
 error_reporting=E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT
```

I've also changed the line in the Smarty_Compiler.class

```
   $source_content = preg_replace_callback($search, create_function ('$matches', "return '"
                                   . $this->_quote_replace($this->left_delimiter) . 'php'
                                   . "' . str_repeat(\"\n\", substr_count('\$matches[1]', \"\n\")) .'"
                                   . $this->_quote_replace($this->right_delimiter)
                                   . "';")
                                   , $source_content);
```

But its not working..

Please advise

Answer (score 0):

[I found that](http://www.acnenomor.com/1334665p1/sugercrm-suitecrm-error-with-pregreplace-and-modifier-e-in-smarty-260-on-php-553) and it seems working:

Replace lines from line 262 with:

```
/* replace special blocks by "{php}" */
   $source_content = preg_replace_callback($search, 
   function($m) {
   return "{php ".str_repeat("\n", substr_count($m[0], "\n"))."}";
   },
   $source_content);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this issue by **replacing the code in include/Smarty/Smarty_Compiler.class.php** file. I replaced the code on line numbers from 262 to 268  with the below mentioned code. After that **delete all the files which are in the cache folder** and reload the page. This issue will be resolved.

```
/* replace special blocks by "{php}" */ 
        $source_content = preg_replace_callback($search, create_function ('$matches', "return '" 
                                                . $this->_quote_replace($this->left_delimiter) . 'php' 
                                                . "' . str_repeat(\"\n\", substr_count('\$matches[1]', \"\n\")) .'" 
                                                . $this->_quote_replace($this->right_delimiter) 
                                                . "';") 
                                                , $source_content);
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

```
    $source_content = preg_replace_callback($search,
        function($m) {
            return $this->_quote_replace($this->left_delimiter) .
                "php ".str_repeat("\n", substr_count($m[0], "\n")) .
                $this->_quote_replace($this->right_delimiter);
        },
        $source_content);
```

- In solution from Axel De Acetis I miss using of function $this->_quote_replace.
- In solution from Sandeep Shivhare I dont like the number 1 in $matches[1], it references wrong string.